# Serving Pdf file from S3 with API gateway and Lamda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have nodejs lamda function that reads s3 file from s3 bucket and and is served by api gateway using Lamda proxy

```
    function readS3(bucket,objectName){
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                AWS.S3.getObject({
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: objectName
                }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('cannot read s3');
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            });
    }

readS3(bucket,objName).then((data)=>{
 let response = {
            statusCode:200,
            headers: {

                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, 
                "Content-Type": 'application/pdf',
                "Content-Disposition": 'filename=test.pdf'
            },
            body: data.Body.toString('utf-8')
        };
callback(null,response);
})
```

The code works fine, except that the downloaded pdf file misses images and some custom formatting. The basic formatting like tables and bold are fine. The pdf in S3 bucket is fine and when I download directly from S3, it does not have any issues.
I have tried different encoding in .toString method but none works. 
It is because of way I am reading content from s3 or is it api gateway's issue?

Comment: It was issue with reading pdf files with Javascript. Not issue with Api gateway.

Comment: What was the issue?